# How to add a task to the collection that Task.WhenAll is waiting for?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Isn't it possible to add a task to the list that `Task.WhenAll` is waiting already?

I want to wait for all the tasks to finish, and there is a possibility to create new tasks after initialization. But here `Task.WhenAll` doesn't wait for the new task that is added to the collection later.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

var task1 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("task #1 started");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        Debug.WriteLine("task #1 finished");
    });

var task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("task #2 started");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    Debug.WriteLine("task #2 finished");
});

var task3 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("task #3 started");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    var inner = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("inner task started");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
        Debug.WriteLine("inner task finished");
    });

    tasks.Add(inner);

    Debug.WriteLine("task #3 finished");
});

tasks.Add(task1);
tasks.Add(task2);
tasks.Add(task3);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Debug.WriteLine("All finished");
```

Output:

```
task #2 started
task #3 started
task #1 started
task #3 finished
inner task started
task #1 finished
task #2 finished
All finished
inner task finished < didn't wait for this to finish
```

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,69351c6da968e5d1) you'll see that the collection/array is copied before the internal mechanisms kick in. Therefore any changes to the original collection will not be observed.

Comment: I think the best you can do is a manual loop - `while(tasks.Count > 0) { await Task.WhenAll(tasks); tasks = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted); }` as a sketch

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks a lot. I think this is the best solution. won't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @Blendester: I find that when people ask this question, what they usually want is a pipeline, like TPL Dataflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` always [copies](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,69351c6da968e5d1) the references to tasks before it actually starts waiting. This does mean that the original collection can be updated whilst the wait is in progress, but `WhenAll` is completely oblivious to these changes.

What I'd suggest, instead, is to run your `WhenAll` in a loop. Something along the lines of:

```
while(tasks.Count > 0) {
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    tasks = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted);
}
```

(With exact details of whether you wish to leave `tasks` itself unmodified, what the exact correct data type is for that variable, etc, left as exercises to be filled in by the reader)

Comment: While I agree this is a solution to the original question, this is definitely a code smell.  If task A relies on the completion of another task B, it stands to reason that task A's implementation should `await` on task B.  See Cheng Chen's response below for more on the relationship.

Answer (score 7):

This is because `tasks.Add(inner)` is executed after `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. To answer your question, first you need to clearify the releationship between *task #3* and *task inner*. IMO the inner task should be part of task #3. That is, task #3 can't finish until the inner task finishes.

```
await inner;   //instead of tasks.Add(inner);
```

Comment: Thank you. but that was for demonstration. New tasks may be added to `tasks` from anywhere. My problem is that I want when the method reaches the end, all the tasks be completed. maybe I'm solving a wrong question